Is it possible to follow links in markdown files when they are concealed?
Say that I have [foo](~/foo.txt) in a markdown file such that when concealed just displays as foo.
Is there any key similar gf such that when used on the displayed text actually follows the link in between the ()?
At the moment, I have to :set conceallevel=0 then I have to move the cursor to what is in between the () hit gf and then :set conceallevel=3 again which is rather tedious.

I can't test this right now, but you can still navigate the concealed the text. Maybe f(lgf will work for you

Thanks. I think it’s a bit cumbersome in addition that motions also consider concealed text making an overall sloppy navigation experience, imho. I rather decrease the conceal level. But thanks anyway:)

I toggle conceal on and off, but I run with it off for the most part :)
